# *ng-for is not rendering DOM but the firebase data is being called

Tags: firebase, angular

I am getting data from firebase by using the below code and i am able to create an array using the below code.

```
fetchPeopleFromFirebase(){
        Firebase fbUsers = this.fbObject.child("posts");
        fbUsers.once("value", (snapshot) => {
          if(snapshot.exists()) {
            snapshot.forEach((object) => {

              console.log("Current Post");
              console.log(object.val());
              Firebase fbUserDetails = this.fbObject.child("users");
              var createdById = object.child('createdBy/_id').val();
              console.log("Checking for : " + createdById)
              fbUserDetails.child(createdById).once("value", (snapshot) => {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                  console.log(snapshot.val());
                }
              });
              this.posts.push(object.val());
            });
          }
          console.log("firebase Data",this.posts);
        }
      }
```

I am storing the data in **this.posts** and i am trying to use it in the view like :

```
*ng-for="#post of posts"
```

But it does not display anything while data is being printed on the console
can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

```
    <ion-content>
    <ion-card *ng-for="#post of posts">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{post.createdBy.avatarUrl}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{post.createdBy.firstName}} {{post.createdBy.lastName}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.createdBy.profession}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
      <ion-list-header>{{post.title}}</ion-list-header>
        <img src="{{post.image}}">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{post.description}}.</p>
      </ion-card-content>

      <ion-item actions class="demo-card">
        <button primary clear item-left (click)="openLikesFollowers()">
          <icon thumbs-up></icon>
          <div>5 followers</div>
        </button>
        <button primary clear item-left (click)="openLikesFollowers()">
          <icon text></icon>
          <div>4 Comments</div>
        </button>
        <p item-left class="time-ago">
          61 views      
        </p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item actions>
        <p item-left class="time-ago">
          +5 collegues are following this      
        </p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you add your view code? i guess ng-for should be : ng-repeat :)

Comment: no .. in angular2 they have changed its syntax `https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html`

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't noticed it's angular2. can you share your view code?

Comment: Can you post the body of your template?

Comment: Yes sure i have updated the question

Comment: See [Sara's presentation on Firebase + Angular 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD0xYicNcaY&feature=youtu.be). It includes sample code, and utilizes [a pipe](https://github.com/sararob/angular2base/blob/master/src/firebasepipe.ts) to make this work intelligently. I'd guess that without something along these lines, there's no way to trigger the change detection in A2.

Comment: I've tried Sara's presentation, but its for the Alpha version, not the current Beta and does not work for me.

Comment: I managed to make it work by creating a service(it uses SET and GET methods)..